# How to receive MultipartFormData on ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, multipartform-data, multipart

I'm working with an iOS guy. He wants to upload images through WebAPI ASP.NET. I've to make a call that can receive those images.
He said he is using AFNetworking to send data through `AFMultipartFormData`. My question is that how can I receive this at my end? Should I take the data in JSON format? Or what measures needs to be done for this purpose? I want to know the whole process as this is my first time working with `MultipartFormData`.
UPDATE
Based on the answer I used this:

```
[HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult GetPatientFilesAction(int id, Model.Patients.PatientFiles patientFile)
        {
            Model.Patients.PatientFiles pFile=new Model.Patients.PatientFiles();
            try
            {
                HttpPostedFile xmlFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

                var fileForm = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
                var fileKey = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Keys[0];
                string[] jsonformat = fileForm.GetValues(fileKey);
                 pFile = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Patients.PatientFiles>(jsonformat[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                pFile.ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
            }
            return Ok(pFile);
        }
```

But the iOS guy got:

> Request failed: unsupported media type (415)

Comment: Are you writing a receiving Web API controller?, or are you to call their existing Web Api end point?

Comment: It's like that... First the images will upload... after all of them are uploaded the rest of the JSON object will come from IOS app.

Comment: You can send both image and json data in the same HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the web API controller you can access the image file using the code below :-

```
HttpPostedFile xmlFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
```

If you have more than one files posted, replace Files[0] with respective count 1 or 2 etc.

And then you can access the JSON using the code :

```
var fileForm = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
var fileKey = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Keys[0];
string[] jsonformat = fileForm.GetValues(fileKey);
var yourModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClassType>(jsonformat[0]);
```

If you have more than one json strings posted, replace jsonformat[0] with respective count 1 or 2 etc.

Comment: bro thank you for your answer. But I've a question as I'm on a very basic level of webAPI. Clear me if I'm wrong... This is what I'll say to the iOS guy "This is the URL: URL_OF_THIS_CALL it a POST request and you can put JSON in your parameters and send that `AFMultipartFormData`. Then using your answer will do all of that for me? I don't know if that makes any sense but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You'll provide the iOS developer with spec saying that your API will accept requests with Content-Type: multipart/form-data and to send the image as  multi-part form data payload. Then they should be able to achieve what's mentioned in the answer.

Comment: he is getting Request failed: unsupported media type (415). Also see the updated question.